# how to show the name of uploaded file as download link in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

In my Django project, I want to show the download link as the name of the uploaded file.

Here is my  `models.py`

```
class QuoteList(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    attached_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/QuoteList/%s/'%owner, blank=True) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.email
```

In `views.py`, I just query an object and send it to the template:

```
def quote_details(request, quote_id):

    quote = get_object_or_404(QuoteList, id=quote_id)
    
    quote.is_opened = True
    quote.save(update_fields=['is_opened', ])
    
    context = {
        'quote': quote,
    }
    return render(request, 'basket/quote_details.html', context)
```

In the template I use the following code to generate download link:

```
{% if quote.attached_file %}
    <div class="">
        <a role="button" 
            href="{{ quote.attached_file.url }}"
            download="{{ quote.attached_file.url }}"
            class="btn btn-light text-dark ml-0">
            Download attachment          <========== the name which is showing to the user
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

how to change the `Download attachment` to the name of uploaded file?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: @iklinac how to strip the path from the name?